Удалить cookie у пользователя с сервера nodejs
Как с сервера nodejs можно удалить cookie у пользователя?

установите в атрибутах отправки куки Expires в дату в прошлом или Max-Age равный 0

Можно путём установки(отправки) времени жизни на -1 или 0.
res.cookie("name", "", {maxAge: -1})

